# f(z) can be expressed as u(x,y) , iv(x,y). Am I doing this right?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

So, $f(z) = z^2 + 4z - 6i$ and I need to express this as $u(x,y)$ , $iv(x,y)$. So, I plug in $z = x+iy$ and simplify.

I am left with this:
$f(x+iy) = x^2 - y^2 + 2xy + 4x + 4iy -6i$.

Now, **how do I express this as $u(x,y)$ and $iv(x,y)$**

*The reason I am doing this is because I read that the derivative of $f(z)$, that is $f\prime(z)$ is $u\prime(x,y) + iv\prime(x,y)$.*

Comment: (a) By collecting like terms. (b) You can find derivatives of polynomials in the usual way; there is rarely a good reason to write $f(z)$ as $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ with $z=x+iy$ to obtain $f'(z)$. (c) You did not calculate $f(x+iy)$ correctly.

Comment: You did right; $u(x,y)$ is the real expression in your result for $f(x+iy)$, while $v(x,y)$ is the imaginary one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you expand $(x+iy)^2$ you get $x^2-y^2+2ixy$, so you have a small typo in your question. Now put $u(x,y) = x^2-y^2+4x$ and $v(x,y) = 2xy+4y-6$. Then
$$f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y).$$

Comment: so who / what decides how u(x,y) and v(x,y) are formed ? just collect like terms ??

Comment: yes; $f(x,y)$ is a complex number: $u$ is the real part of $f(x,y)$, while $v$ is the imaginary part.

Comment: all terms with $i$ go into v(x,y)? :)

Comment: Yes. Say that $z = x + i y$. Then the *real* and *imaginary* parts of $z$ are defined to be $\mathrm{Re}(z) = x$ and $\mathrm{Im}(z) = y$ respectively. With that notation, $u(x,y) = \mathrm{Re}(f(x,y))$ and $v(x,y) = \mathrm{Im}(f(x,y))$

Answer (score 1):

A comment on the statement:

*The reason I am doing this is because I read that the derivative of $f(z)$ , that is $f'(z)$  is $u'(x,y)+iv'(x,y)$*.

The partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ of $f(z)$ in $z=x+iy$ are defined as

$$f_x:=u_x+iv_x,$$

and

$$f_y:=u_y+v_y.$$

In your question you write $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2+4x$ and $v(x,y)=2xy+4y-6$.
The partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$
exist, as both $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are polynomials.

$f$ *differentiable* (I interpret this as your *derivative* of $f$ at $z$) 
at $z$ is a much stronger condition; in fact $f$ is differentiable at $z$ if the limit

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow o}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$

exists (independently on the *complex* vector $h$ we choose!). Differentiability at $z$ implies the Cauchy Riemann equations $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ for $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$, where $z=x+iy$. Given $f$ as in your question, you can quickly check that it is differentiable at $z$.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the typo. Can you post an updated answer ? :)

Comment: Sure! I do it right now

Comment: It is beginning to make sense now. But before I jump to take a derivative , I must first see if it is differentiable using Cauchy-Reimann Equation, right ???

Comment: The question is: what do you mean with *derivative*? If you mean *differentiable* as I showed in my answer, then if the C.R. equations are not satisfied you cannot have differentiability. If *derivative* means either $f_x$ or $f_y$, all you need is to introduce $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$.

Comment: **The question is: what do you mean with derivative?** by that I mean what I learned in my calculus class in high school. $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ and now just extending it to complex numbers $\frac{d}{dx}f(z)$ *I hope I am making sense*

Comment: When moving to complex numbers, *derivative* must be carefully dealt with...you cannot take the definition for real numbers and apply it straightforwardly to the complex case. Some care is needed, and that was the aim of my answer. Please, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function, under Definition. The important piece of information is that the limit in the definition is taken considering *any* complex vector $z$.

Comment: So, the subtle difference is that the limit must exist, in Holomorphic functions. And for that Cauchy Reiman equations are used...

Comment: This is correct; to check the limit directly can be difficult, sometimes. To compute the CR equations is much easier :-)

Comment: So basically... if limit at that point exists , slope (derivative) can be found. If not, well $f(z)$ is not differentiable for that given z.. right ? *this is the last counter question , I promise*

Comment: To visualize tangent lines to a complex function $f$ you should make a $(z,f(z))$ plot, like in the real case. How to put the complex numbers $z$ on the horizontal axis? I cannot do that, because I should choose an ordering on $\mathbb C$, which does not exist.